# load multiple images

Tags: three.js

How to load a set of images each with a different position to a webGL renderer?
I had 4 images (part of a single image)
each image is of fixed size 256x256 and have position info available
image1 is at position 0,0
image 2 - pos(0,256)
image3 - pos(256,0)
image4 - pos(256, 256)

how to load them properly in threejs

Answer (score 2):

You can use a canvas as texture source. For example, if you want to arrange your tiles in a 512x512 texture, you can do something like:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// load tiles into a canvas
context.drawImage(image0, 0, 0, 256, 256);
context.drawImage(image1, 256, 0, 256, 256);
context.drawImage(image2, 0, 256, 256, 256);
context.drawImage(image3, 256, 256, 256, 256);

// tiles merged into a single image attached to texture
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
```

The parameters of drawImage in this case are: imageSource, x-position, y-position, width, height.

you can read about the drawImage function here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

This way your 4 images would be loaded as a single texture which you can be used on a plane (or any type of geometry). You have more options besides the images with a canvas, you can simply fill the canvas with colors, leave empty space between images, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It will be some background?

If images are so small i thing it will be better to join them and load as a single picture.

Generally you can put THREE.Plane with texture as your image. Something like this:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "image.png" );
texture.minFilter = texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;      //If you wish to have some filtering when moveing camera
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 256, 256 ),
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture} ) );
plane.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );                                   //Different for each image
```

Comment: i had a lot of images in the form of tiles. i cant stitch images in this case. Is there any way to have multiple images in a single plane?

Comment: There is a threat on github about this. Follow the link: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/533

Comment: how to use GeometryUtils.merge? does anyone have an example

Comment: See three.js code: Merge two geometries or geometry and geometry from object (using object's transform) function ( geometry1, object2 /* mesh | geometry */ ). So I think you have to place that object properly each other and then merge them. But I have better idea. I think you should create 4 planes (each for single image). Place them close to each other. Fill them with texture. Then create single THREE.Object3D and add there your planes. That new object will beahave as a container and it will be possible to switch images on each plane (after merging I think i won't be possible).

Comment: I prefer the idea of creating 4 containers and placing texture in each of them. But I have a problem. All tiles are not just close
x1,y1 =(-251,-63)
x2,y2 = (5,-63)
x3,y3 = (261,-63)
x4,y4 = (517,-63)

so the tiles are not place exactly on top of another one there is a shift